# Regex to extract data on some lines while discarding others

Tags: c#, regex

I have these SQL DB creation scripts that I want to extract table names from to create GRANT accesses to.

To extract the actual names isn't a problem:

```
^CREATE TABLE ([\w\.]+)[\r\n]+
```

However, if I want to just do a `Regex.Replace` to create the GRANT statements out of these names (in group 1), *I'm stuck with all the lines that don't match that I'd like to get rid off*.

e.g.

For:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.t_MyType
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexMyType ON dbo.t_MyType (TypeName)

CREATE TABLE dbo.t_MyType2
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexMyType ON dbo.t_MyType2 (TypeName)
```

I get:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.t_MyType TO db_read(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexMyType ON dbo.t_MyType (TypeName)

GRANT SELECT ON dbo.t_MyType2 TO db_read(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexMyType ON dbo.t_MyType2 (TypeName)
```

So the question is: What are the regex and replace string pair I need to use in order to get the following result?

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.t_MyType TO db_read
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.t_MyType2 TO db_read
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do a replace, just enumerate through the [MatchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) returned by [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) and build a new sql file. (You will need to modify your regex a bit)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string query = 
@"CREATE TABLE dbo.t_MyType
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexMyType ON dbo.t_MyType (TypeName)

CREATE TABLE dbo.t_MyType2
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TypeName VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexMyType ON dbo.t_MyType2 (TypeName)";

    string matchString = @"CREATE TABLE ([\w\.]+)";


    var matches = Regex.Matches(query, matchString);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("GRANT SELECT ON {0} TO db_read", match.Groups[1]).AppendLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Huh. Indeed, that works and is probably the best thing to do. Now that being said: could I, theoretically, get a group that encompasses all that I don't need so I can discard it in a `Regex.Replace` call?